# Am I exploitable to CVE-2023-20862?

Tags: vulnerability, cve, spring-framework

I am trying to analyze whether I am exploitable to the new CVE in spring security.

As per Spring they mention the following:

Specifically, an application is vulnerable when any of the following is true:

- You are using the SecurityContextHolderFilter or requireExplicitSave(true) and you are using Spring Security's logout support with serialized sessions (e.g. Spring Session) and invalidateHttpSession(false)
- You are logging users out manually by saving an empty SecurityContext into the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository
- You have a custom SecurityContextRepository that does not rely on the HttpSession

An application is not vulnerable if any of the following is true:

- You are still using the deprecated SecurityContextPersistenceFilter or requireExplicitSave(false)
- You are using Spring Security's logout support with in-memory sessions.
- You are not saving an empty SecurityContext into the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository

Reference: https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-20862

The upgrade of spring is very costly, so I if I can tell that this CVE is not exploitable in my case, then that would be awesome. From the description above, how can I check the points mentioned if I have access to the code but I am not the developer, so I'm not the expert in the code.
I tried searching for the keyword "HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository", then I found zero matches, can I tell that my application is not saving an empty SecurityContext into the HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository as mentioned in the last point?

Comment: Hello @A.Hersean, 
Okay I see your point, If I could share the code I would have did, but I can't unfortunately.
Now the question is, how I check the above checklist shared by Spring in my code? 
I'm not a developer, so I'm not en expert, can you give a hint? like is it the right approach how I searched for the keyword in the example I gave ? or ?

Comment: In other words, how I check for the points below:
* You are still using the deprecated SecurityContextPersistenceFilter or requireExplicitSave(false)
* You are using Spring Security's logout support with in-memory sessions.

* You are not saving an empty SecurityContext into the

* HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository

Comment: *"The upgrade of spring is very costly"* - In the most cases it is not true. **What Spring version do you use?** Why do you think it is relevant in your case at all? If you use 5.6.x or 5.7.x, then upgrade to 5.7.8 is trivial. If 5.8.x. then upgrade to 5.8.3 is trivial. If 6.0.x, then upgrade to 6.0.3 is trivial. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @mentallurg, my problem is the code is very huge, and it has several versions, on old versions of the code it is using old versions of Spring, there is no one verision.
So if I have my app on version 1 then it has on Spring version different from version 2 of my app. I hope you understand the complexity, and the issue is not only in Spring, but I gave it as an example because in this CVE Spring explicitly mentions the cases where Spring is exploitable and where it is not.

Comment: @ethicalhacker: There is a list of "Affected Spring Products and Versions". on the page that you linked. Even if you use multiple versions, just check if these versions are on this list.

Comment: @mentallurg, NO NO you misunderstood me, I meant I have an app called X.
X is a huge app and it is being developed since 2010, so I have X.1 till X.100, so 100 different versions of X, and on each version we have different Spring versions, and for older versions of X it is hard to upgrade Spring (very costly). If I can analyze in a way and know if this CVE is not exploitable, that will save much work ! actually it will save work that can't be done.

Comment: @ethicalhacker: I mean, you *don't need* to upgrade, if the version is not affected. For instance, if you have versions 5.1.x, 5.2.x, 5.3.x, 5.4.x, 5.5.x, 5.6.x, then *none* of them needs a fix/upgrade, because none of them is in the list of affected versions. You need upgrade only, if you use versions 5.7.0 to 5.7.7, 5.8.0 to 5.8.2, or 6.0.0 to 6.0.2.

Comment: @mentallurg, Ah okay, so yes the versions I am using are affected. 
But still my question here is how I know if I am using an affected Spring version, if I am exploitable? noting that Spring mentioned a checklist which can determine if vulenrability exists or. In other words, how do I check for the points mentioned by Spring? Is it easy to check them ? is it a simple seach in the codeline for some keywords?

Comment: @ethicalhacker: There is no trick. Just check everything what Spring mentions. E.g. they say vulnerability affects SecurityContextHolderFilter. Go to Spring source code. Check from what till what version this class exists. In this case it exists since 5.7.0. Suppose you use 5.7.2. This version is affected by vulnerability. Check if it used in your code directly. Check if it used in your code directly, e.g. if it is used in some Spring classes that you use explicitly or implicitly. Or hire a developer or a company that can help you.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, my huge code base is on Spring 3 so version wise, it would be costly for me too.

Comment: @SridharSarnobat, unfortunately it does not make me feel better :p. I need to know how such CVEs can be assessed, and I just gave this CVE as an example, but I have a lot of other CVEs in 3rd parties that I cannot update.